# Managing a football club website

Tags: cms

I need to make a website for a football club. The club is fairly large with a lot of players and a lot of volounteers.

I need a CMS that, at the very least, can manage teams, leagues and cups. I also need a section for logged in users, where coaches can administer their teams, contact their players and post event (such as training, cups, matches etc.) can display news on the front end.

I would like, if the CMS could manage a community, where people can get in touch with eachother.

I need to be able to mange:

- users and user groups
- events - cups, leagues, training, cources
- fora/discussion boards
- News section
- Newsletters
- Messaging system to notify certain groups of events

I have some experience with setting up Joomla, Drupal and Wordpress, but I can't seem to find a sollution with plugins that just works for my needs.
Does anyone know of a CMS with or without the use of plugins that can cater to my needs?